# Using non-apple g++ on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: macos, compilation, g++

Is it possible to use the stock (non-apple) version of g++ on Mac OSX 10.7? I want to be able to use the stock g++ without running a virtual linux box on my mac. The reason I want to do this is because apple's version of g++ doesn't warn you when there are unused variables and etc. I'm doing some assessed C++ problems in my numerical methods course and I want to make sure I'm not making any mistakes.

It was suggested I make a symbolic link to a linux version of g++ for compiling the code for the assessments. How do I go about doing that?

Thanks

Comment: You may just need to turn on the specific warnings that you need, either via -Wall/-Wextra or using the specific -Wunused-XXX switches

Answer (score 0):

A linux version of the compiler will not work on what is (essentially) a bsd port.
Are you sure that the current version of g++ cannot warn on the conditions you expect?  
Finally, if #2 is true, there is nothing stopping you from getting another version of g++ (compiled for MacOSX) that doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Note that projects such as MacPorts and Homebrew have newer versions of gcc ready to run on Mac OS X if needed: see http://www.macports.org/ and http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: I haven't lost interest, I only posted this question yesterday. I'll investigate, I'm a bit busy but I'll reply within a week. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A binary for `g++`  for Linux won't run on MacOSX.

You could compile GCC from its source code; use the latest [release](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) i.e. **4.6.2**. But that requires some work. Be sure to follow the  [installation instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/), in particular care about dependencies (like PPL & Cloog) and configure (appropriately) and compile in a build tree outside of the source tree.